# Using Radio Buttons in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 - Coding error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

For some reason, the first "If" statement works when I debug but when I try any other radio button or use the same button but try to make the second "If" statement true, I hit the "Calculate Reward Points" button but it does not calculate. It only calculates the first "If" statement. Here is my code. I apologize if my lingo is not up to par. I am only taking this class because it is required. I attache

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Const basic1 As Double = 0.03
    Const basic2 As Double = 0.05
    Const basic3 As Double = 0.08
    Const basic4 As Double = 0.1
    Const basic5 As Double = 0.15
    Dim totalLabel As Double
    Dim doubleReward As Double

    Double.TryParse(RewardDisplay.Text, doubleReward)
    Double.TryParse(TotalTextBox.Text, totalLabel)

    If basicRadioButton.Checked AndAlso totalLabel < 100 Then
        RewardDisplay.Text = totalLabel * basic1
    ElseIf basicRadioButton.Checked AndAlso totalLabel < 200 or >= 100 Then
        RewardDisplay.Text = totalLabel * basic2
    ElseIf basicRadioButton.Checked AndAlso totalLabel >= 200 Then
        RewardDisplay.Text = totalLabel * basic3
    ElseIf standardRadioButton.Checked AndAlso totalLabel < 199 Then
        RewardDisplay.Text = totalLabel * basic3
    ElseIf standardRadioButton.Checked AndAlso totalLabel >= 200 Then
        RewardDisplay.Text = totalLabel * basic4
    ElseIf premiumRadioButton.Checked AndAlso totalLabel < 299 Then
        RewardDisplay.Text = totalLabel * basic4
    ElseIf premiumRadioButton.Checked AndAlso totalLabel >= 300 Then
        RewardDisplay.Text = totalLabel * basic5
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to see in debug mode the values of the variables
 basicRadioButton.Checked and totalLabel to understand why the algorithm does not go to what you are expecting.
Simplify you code, maybe doing something link this

```
If basicRadioButton.Checked then
     'the totalLabel conditions now
end if

if  standardRadioButton.Checked  then
     'the totalLabel conditions now
end if

if  premiumRadioButton.Checked  then
     'the totalLabel conditions now
end if
```

This will help you find your error.

Comment: I tried simplifying it below to separate "If" statements and it still only calculates the first "If" statement

    If basicRadioButton.Checked AndAlso totalLabel < 100 Then
            RewardDisplay.Text = totalLabel * basic1

        End If
        If basicRadioButton.Checked AndAlso totalLabel < 200 or >= 100 Then
            RewardDisplay.Text = totalLabel * basic2

        End If
        If basicRadioButton.Checked AndAlso totalLabel >= 200 Then
            RewardDisplay.Text = totalLabel * basic3

Comment: But what are the values of the basicRadioButton.Checked and totalLabel  before the If? you can see using a breakpoint before the If and putting the mouse in the variables to see the values. 
If the values are wrong the problem is before the IFs